# How to 'remember' a value to insert into two tables in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a trigger that I want to insert the same random value into two tables. How do I do this?

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertTrigger AFTER INSERT ON TableAB 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableA(id, num) VALUES(RANDOM(), 1);
    INSERT INTO TableB(id, num) VALUES(??, 1);
END;
```

I am not really using Random, but my own custom sqlite function which essentially does the same thing, but I need to remember that value to insert into TableB. How do I do that?

Comment: sqlite doesn't support variables, but you could possibly set up a throwaway temp table with a single field/value that temporarily holds your randomv value, and select from that temp table into your two insert queries.

Comment: @MarcB You should do that as an answer…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite has no such thing as variables, but you could read the value from the record that you had just inserted into the first table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insertTrigger
AFTER INSERT ON TableAB
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TableA(id, num) VALUES(RANDOM(), 1);
    INSERT INTO TableB(id, num) SELECT id, 1
                                FROM TableA
                                WHERE rowid = last_insert_rowid();
END;
```

Comment: very creative solution, i like it :)